# Есть ли слово "прамать"?

Tags: окказионализмы

Праматерь есть, а вот такая форма? Вроде же нет ограничений, к какому существительному поставить приставку "пра"? Выходит, если автор хочет, то никаким правилом ему здесь не возразить?

Comment: Единственный попался печатный случай (предложено как термин, буквальное толкование иероглифа со значением "прародительница") в издании АН СССР: Краткие сообщения Института народов Азии, т. 53, 1962 https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=YM0TAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA9&img=1&pgis=1&dq=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&sig=ACfU3U2HQMBaHYsdOehK_xjrBW86IdW-AA&edge=0 и https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=YM0TAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA10&img=1&pgis=1&dq=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&sig=ACfU3U0bEGUpQ8lIu3t0ax5It_XsfXD7Qg&edge=0

Comment: Прамати = прародительница наша, Ева. Праотец = Адам. (Из статей, рядом находящихся в ЦСС Дьяченко.)

Comment: @shampar: "прамати" — это вроде звательный падеж.

Comment: А какой корень и какого его значение ?